# Timed out error when using python to send an email

Tags: python

I want to use python to send an email. The code is listed below. How can I solve the operation timed out problem?

I have already turn on the Less Secure APPS.

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib

from_addr = 'my@gmail.com'
to_addr = 'to@gmail.com'
password = 'mypass'

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com')
server.connect('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(from_addr, password)
msg = MIMEText('send my python', 'plain', 'utf-8')

server.sendmail(from_addr, to_addr, msg.as_string())
server.quit()
```

That is the response:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/daniel/PycharmProjects/风便/email_send.py", line 9, in    <module>
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
(code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 336, in connect
self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 307, in _get_socket
self.source_address)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 727, in create_connection
raise err
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 716, in create_connection
sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [Errno 60] Operation timed out
```

Comment: Not an expert on smtp but this smells like a connectivity issue. If that's the case, 1) make sure your computer are able to reach the smtp server, 2) make sure the smtp server allows your computer to connect. (there are probably configuration you need to set on your gmail account.) Could you try connect to the same smtp server:port using another utility from your laptop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried your code on my desktop (substituting my credentials, of course), I got a slightly different error:

```
OSError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
```

But we seem to be running on different platforms. The documentation for the constructor of the server object implies that if you do not specify both the server address and port, then a connect will not be explicitly done *and you only specified the server address*. But that is not the case. If you look at your stack trace closely, you can see that your exception is occurring in the construction of the server object and that during this construction it is calling the `connect` method, presumably with a port value of 0, which is the default port parameter value for the constructor. On the Windows platform, using port 0 results in a different type of exception. The solution is to either specify no parameters when you construct the sever object:

```
server = smtplib.SMTP()
```

or do what I do, which is to specify both the server *and* port address, in which case there is no need to call `connect` or `ehlo`:

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(from_addr, password)
msg = MIMEText('send my python', 'plain', 'utf-8')
server.sendmail(from_addr, to_addr, msg.as_string())
server.quit()
```

Comment: I tried what you did and it works. I could not totally understand the error since I am a newbie in Python. Anyway, I really appreciate your kindness. Wish you all the best.

Answer (score 0):

If you using VPN in background, try to temporary disable them and then run again, your code works.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).